# Unable to install WebPack CLI

Tags: npm, webpack, installation

I'm trying out webpack for the first time, but I cant even get past the installation of webpack-cli

I get this error

```
{ Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at runCommand.then (C:\Users\Henrik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:142:5)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

When I run webpack  it suggest to auto install it, but fails at that.

Any suggestions?

-- EDIT 1 --

My package.json looks like this:

```
    {
  "name": "webpacktest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

I've tried running this : "npm install webpack-cli --save-dev" amongst various other suggestions found all over the web

Comment: What command do you run? Can we see for least your package.json? You already try install `npm i -g webpack-cli` ?

Comment: Question edited to ansver your question

Comment: Cool! And you try install globally like `npm i -g webpack-cli` and remove locally dependencie? `npm uninstall -D webpack-cli`

Comment: It's hilarious isn't it? Cannot install webpack-cli because module webpack-cli can't be found. Installing globally generates tons of errors too. I can't understand that a popular tool such as webpack won't even install without errors.

Comment: Yea. I feel that webpack have added to my production-time. If I were just making one project and only needed 1 configuration, then it would propably be a boon, but I have a lot of wery different projects so I spend a lot of time configuring WebPack now. I dread the dat that on of the packages I use everywhere (e.g. vue) needs an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you might be trying to use a global webpack package with a local webpack-cli package.

Try adding `webpack` to your devDependencies and running webpack from inside an npm/yarn script, and if that doesn't work try uninstalling your global webpack binary.

Comment: Yea..  This must've been it..  Some global/local installation-stuff..

I uninstalled and ran this "npm install webpack webpack-cli --save-dev" and now it seems to be working (at least a bit further).

Comment: @HenrikClausen Glad you figured it out! Make sure to mark this answer as correct for anyone else that comes along.

Comment: @OmidMaturi I rejected your edit because it's the exact opposite of what my post stated. OP needed to _remove_ webpack from their global dependencies or at least use a local copy, not _install_ a global copy. 

Make sure to read and understand an approved post before hijacking it with the same contents as your own post. That's why you can make a separate post to begin with.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
npm install -g --save-dev webpack-cli
```

Comment: I spent 4 hours on countless options and this line saved me!

Answer (score 1):

I executed your package.json and it worked without any errors
Try deleting the node_modules folder and run the comand **npm install** from the prompt